# Windows 10 bluetooth can't connect to any device

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I'm having some problems with pairing/connecting devices on bluetooth and I really can't figure out the problem. Finding devices is no problem, but I just can't connect to any device.

What I have tried already:

- Restart bluetooth support service
- run bluetooth troubleshooter
- update bluetooth drivers
- uninstall bluetooth drivers and manually reinstall new ones

There could be 2 things that caused this problem and I'm not very sure which one it is:

1. I recently dualbooted to Linux Mint (on Linux Mint Bluetooth works perfectly by the way so it's not a hardware problem)
2. I recently bought a computer mouse with a bluetooth usb module. I have tried connecting to bluetooth without the usb module ofcourse.
   As stated above I have already unistalled all of these drivers and
   manually reinstalled them so I don't think this is the problem, but
   I just mention it because it's remarkable that bluetooth stopped
   working at around the same time I bought the bluetooth mouse.

Hope someone can help me here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Windows Verison?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the error code or go to the regedit and check your problem there, I'm damn sure that your Bluetooth will be fixed from there. If not working then change your Bluetooth.

Comment: I don't find any particular errors in regedit. Also I don't really get what you mean by 'change your bluetooth'