# Windows10 Bluetooth error: "We didn't get any response from the device. Try connecting again."

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Same problem like [Windows 10 Bluetooth can't connect to any device](https://superuser.com/questions/1425746/windows-10-bluetooth-cant-connect-to-any-device)

*Error: Didn't get any response from the device*

[image: Error - Didn't get any response from the device - Screenshot]

What I have done:

1. Restart Bluetooth support service.
2. Run Bluetooth troubleshooter.
3. Uninstall Bluetooth drivers and reinstall.

I tried to reinstall the system on the other hard disk partitions with the same system image. The Bluetooth function is normal in the new system.
So I decided to fix the problem by modifying the old system registry.

According to the class ID of the Bluetooth hardware found in the device manager, the problem is fixed by querying the registry values related to the old and new systems.

*Information: Registry*

[image: Information - Registry - Screenshot]

*Information: The class ID of the Bluetooth hardware*

[image: Information - The class ID of the Bluetooth hardware - Screenshot]

Can anyone give me some suggestions for solving this problem? I am grateful!

Comment: But I can connect the Galaxy Earbuds with Android

Comment: @SmartManoj are you also having this issue? I'm unable to pair my Sony WH-1000XM3 to my windows 10 PC since yesterday. I'm wondering is it some recent windows 10 update, because the headphones still connect with all of my other devices.

Comment: Ok, so I found some microsoft thread where someone suggested doing a cold boot. I'd already tried everything else, it's been two days of not being able to pair anything bluetooth. I'd tried reinstalling drivers, unpairing everything, weird bluetooth cli tools to debug.

I believe I had a different problem that this question, because all of my devices were appearing as "Unknown device".

What solved it for me just now was physically removing the power cable, and starting the computer to find everything pairs again as normal. I don't understand, nor do I want to...

Comment: @Alan Yes but I'm in 1909. What is your Bluetooth version?. Did you mean you rebooted?